# Expected NullPointerException with ConcurrentHashMap doesn't show up

Tags: java, concurrency, iterator, concurrenthashmap

I don't understand why this code doesn't throw a NullPointerException after the line where I do iterator.next(); the JavaDoc says:

> The view's iterator [..] guarantees to traverse elements as they
>   existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not
>   guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

In all the runs I did it never reflected any modifications, otherwise cur.getKey() would give me a NullPointerException, since I removed an element. I even put a sleep to facilitate the error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

class MapWorker implements Runnable {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map;

    public MapWorker(final int i, final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Set key and value to search for
        final Integer key = 3;
        final String value = "three";

        final Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        System.out.println("Map is " + map);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final Entry<Integer, String> cur = iterator.next();

            if (cur.getKey()==key && cur.getValue().equals(value)) {
                iterator.remove();
                System.out.println("Removed");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MapExercise {
    static final int NUM_WORKERS = 5;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Create and populate map
        final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
        map.put(1, "one");
        map.put(2, "two");
        map.put(3, "three");
        map.put(4, "four");
        map.put(5, "five");

        // Create and init worker threads
        final List<Thread> allThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++)
            allThreads.add(new Thread(new MapWorker(i, map)));

        // Start worker threads
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        for (final Thread t : allThreads)
            t.start();

        // Wait for worker threads to finish
        for (final Thread t : allThreads)
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                /* do nothing */
            }
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as `iterator.hasNext()` returns true there is still an element. That is why you are not receiving a NullPointerException.

Comment: Say that iterator.hasNext() return true; meanwhile(context switch) another thread deletes the number 3, which should have been the next element of the iterator. Context returns to the previous thread which has already entered the while(iterator.hasNext()). What does iterator.next() returns? Whatever it returns I use it afterwards, thing that should throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation on [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent
>   retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries.
>   Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements
>   reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the
>   creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be
>   used by only one thread at a time.

It basically means that the iterator sees an old version of the map, while the "real" map may have undergone a series of modifications.

You can convince yourself that this is the case by testing the existence of the key prior to removing it through the iterator:

```
        if (cur.getKey()==key && cur.getValue().equals(value)) {
            boolean exists = map.containsKey(cur.getKey());
            iterator.remove();
            System.out.println("Removed: " + exists);
        }
```